# Unity 3D rename workspaces?

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces

Any good way to rename workspaces in Unity 3D (e.g. compiz)?

[image]

Back when I was running metacity (e.g. old Gnome 2) we could called them useful names like "Personal", "Work", "Development", "Media", etc.

Comment: Could you explain iin your question what you mean by workspaces and renaming them?

Comment: FYI - I've filed an enhancement request with indicator-workspaces to have a new option that will display the workspace name instead of the number: https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-workspaces/+bug/1038251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the application "Configuration Editor", install it using this command in terminal:

`sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`

Now, open Configuration Editor in the Dash. You will want to navigate to this path:

/apps/metacity/workspace_names

Now, rename name_1, name_2,... whatever you would like. :)

If it doesn't work initially, you may want to log out and log in.

Edit: This does NOT work with the right click option that you requested, sadly. It does work with the `indicator-workspaces` package and some other things on Ubuntu. Thought this would help :(

Edit Again: [This link](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/compiz-098-landed-ubuntu-1210-workspace-naming-and-numerous-fixes) shows that the newest version of compiz that will be in 12.10 WILL have this capability. So, it looks like we'll have to wait another 2 months or so, then we can do this all we want. :)

Comment: Yup - already did that, but compiz as window manager doesn't use the new names.

Comment: That would explain it. There HAS to be a fix somewhere, but I'm clueless as to how.

Comment: We are in the same place on this now!  I see that the change took in indicator-workspaces...thats something at least.  Seems like there has to be a way....

Comment: http://www.iloveubuntu.net/compiz-098-landed-ubuntu-1210-workspace-naming-and-numerous-fixes

Take a look at this--This looks promising and exciting! I wonder if we can either get this plugin on the 12.04 compiz or update to the newest compiz.

Comment: Nice find...so worst case, all we have to do is wait for the backport.  Add this to your answer and I'll check it...

Comment: FAIL!  Just upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 and was dissapointed to discover all the Compiz "Name Workspaces" plugin does is flash the name on the screen when you switch.  Lame....

Comment: Sigh.... I used to enjoy Ubuntu but now I feel like we really can't even truly make it our own anymore.