# Ubuntu 14.04.1 (unity): rename workspaces

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

(related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175456/unity-3d-rename-workspaces), but that is outdated)

How can I set the name of the workspaces?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this through the `CompizConfig Settings Manager`

If you have not installed CCSM, just open the terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open CCSM and go to `Workspace Naming` under `Window Management`. If you can not see Workspace Naming, open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins.
```

Enable `Workspace Naming` plugin. If you get a message asking you to enable the `Text` plugin, enable it. When you enable the plugin, your screen may appear weird for a while and may take you back to the log in screen. Don't freak out, just log back in and open CCSM once again and follow the following steps to change the name of the workspace.

After this all you have to do is select the workspace(It is called Viewport in this menu) and click edit to change the name.

**NOTE**: CCSM is an extremely powerful tool but it is also possible for you to ruin your system by doing something wrong. So  please be cautious when using the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to the "Viewport *n*" labels appearing when you switch workspaces? It has been said that "[there is no concept of workspace names](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/934549/comments/2)".

But you can make your own. Unity's workspace switcher move's compiz's "viewport" around over a big desktop. If you install *wmctrl* you can slide it around yourself. See [this script](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-script-for-automatic-viewport-changing-and-other-wm-stuff-works-with-compiz-838827/) for details. Perhaps you could adapt it to understand names for each workspace?

You can also programattically change the geometry of the workspace by modifying the dimensions of the workspace grid. It is the *hsize* and *vsize* properties visible via the *gsettings* tool:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/
```